# Why is this this error: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I use workbox from CDN `importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.6.1/workbox-sw.js');`

And if use the `staleWhileRevalidate` strategy I get this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': 'only-if-cached' can be set only with 'same-origin' mode`

The error message disappears if I change the `staleWhileRevalidate` with another (for example NetworkFirst).

Ps: The error occurs only in Chrome when I open the Developer Tools.

Comment: Have you checked [this chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348877)?